# MACD with Python Pandas on 0 index always equals to 0

Tags: python, pandas, moving-average, alpha-vantage

I'm trying to plot a MACD indicator using Python Pandas. The problem I encountered is when I'm trying to calculate the short and long moving averages.

```
exp1 = close.y.ewm(span=12, adjust=False).mean()
exp2 = close.y.ewm(span=26, adjust=False).mean()
```

`close` is my dataframe with two columns for index and stocks closing prices. I get the stock `TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY` information from *Alpha Vantage* API.

Now for some reason I always get the same result in the first index for both `exp1` and `exp2`

`exp1`

[image: exp1 series print]

`exp2`

[image]

As you can see, the 0 index on both series are identical and later data are different. So when I try to calculate the MACD, the last graph point is always equal to 0.

```
macd = exp1 - exp2
```

[image]

I thought that this might be normal for MACD, but every graph of MACD that I have seen, the last point between MACD and the single line are not at 0 (as seen in the picture from Yahoo Finance)

[image]

So I'm not sure what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Is the question about MACD, or about the behavior of ewm in pandas?

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is fine. The strange behavior you see for the first data point is a result of the fact that you EWM assumes infinite history*, while in practice we don't have that. As a result, the EWM for time 0 (1743.67500 in your case) is the value of the series at time 0 (basically, the average of X is X). As a result, EWM with span 26 for time 0 is identical to EWM with span 12 for time 0, and your MACD for time 0 is 0.

In the context of MACD, what you're (typically) looking for is crossovers between the MACD and the stock (or instrument) value. MACD and the value will meet at time 0, but it's not a crossover because there's nothing before time 0.

The simple solution is to chart your MACD graph starting at day N (eg. day 15). That is, if you're interested in MACD for the period starting on June 1st, create a data frame that calculates MACD starting May 1st or May 15th, but only chart the data for June 1st and on.

* Note - [pandas' documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/computation.html#exponentially-weighted-windows) about EWM states that "... there is an assumption that 0 is not an ordinary value but rather an exponentially weighted moment of the infinite series up to that point".

Comment: I had a feeling, that something like this would be the problem. But how do I solve it? Do I need to some how reorder index'es in descending order, so that ewm correctly sees the history?

Comment: Updated the post. See the paragraph starting with "the simple solution".